# Ajax response after first submit give data in JSON + serialized form. How could I retrieve the original values in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, serialization

I'm using ajax to save data for multi part forms. Now I want to save the each form data on next button click. I used form data to serialize. But the format of data is not as I want.

`var event_quote_fields = $('#event-form').serialize();
        var data = {
            action: 'ode_plugin_save_ajax_request',
            event_quote_fields: event_quote_fields
        }
        console.log('data is' + data);
        $.post(ode_params.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
             alert('The server responded2: ' + response);
             var dataString = JSON.stringify(response);
             alert('The server responded2: ' + dataString);
             $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ajax/ajax.php",
                data: {sample: dataString},
                dataType:'JSON', 
                success: function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                    // put on console what server sent back...
                }
            });
        });`

**Output:**

> coverage_limit=%241+million+occurence+%2F+%242+million+aggregate&need_a_waiver=on&water_activities=on&alcohol_instructed=on&name%5B%5D=test&address_1%5B%5D=arizona&email%5B%5D=test%40gmail.com&address%5B%5D=Arizona%2C+United+States&city%5B%5D=Arizona&state%5B%5D=AZ&zip%5B%5D=85554&phone%5B%5D=(124)+578-5421

How do I get the form fields data in a php array ?

Answer (score 0):

You used .serialize() method, so you can send the form results as parameters.

```
var event_quote_fields = $('#event-form').serialize();
    var data = {
        action: 'ode_plugin_save_ajax_request',
        event_quote_fields: event_quote_fields
    }
    console.log('data is' + data);
    $.post(ode_params.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
         var dataString = JSON.stringify(response);
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ajax/ajax.php",
            data: dataString, // just send the string
            dataType:'JSON', 
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
                // put on console what server sent back...
            }
        });
    });
```

In the ajax.php you can access parameters like this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    // do some stuff
}
```